# Canvas images do not load until click event... I want to load when page loads, how?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onload

I am creating Battleships, the board game on an HTML5 canvas. I have a problem loading my ship images when the page is loaded. For some reason, the ship images only show when I click somewhere on the screen.

#### background info:

1.I have 2 canvas elements, each with 2 contexts

2.If I put the PlayerGrid.js before  the OpponentGrid.js I have to click on the screen to get my ships to show up.

3.The Draw() is what draws the grid, and the images once they are created from the createShips(). createships() simply creates different ship objects and assigns images to each object.

4.I DO TRY CALLING DRAW() in many places, the onload, and the createShips(), but they still do not show.

Does anybody know what it could be? Is it a conflict in the context or canvases? The ship images DO show when I put the OpponentGrid.js BEFORE my PlayerGrid.js, but then there is a huge problem with my XMLHttpRequest that isn't worth solving.

How else should I call my Draw method after everything is loaded? Should I call my Draw() in my Battleship.html at the end somewhere?

Comment: will u pls post ur code in jdfiddle then only we can help u.if u call draw canvas method after page loads complete it might work

Comment: Why do you need 4 contexts for 2 canvas elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how to be sure all your images are loaded before you use them**

Code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/nD5jr/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

  var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas1");
  var ctx1=canvas1.getContext("2d");
  var canvas2=document.getElementById("canvas2");
  var ctx2=canvas2.getContext("2d");

  var imageURLs=[];
  var imagesOK=0;
  var imagesFailed=0;
  var imgs=[];
  imageURLs.push("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/New_York_City_at_night_HDR_edit1.jpg");
  imageURLs.push("http://www.freebestwallpapers.info/bulkupload//20082010//Places/future-city.jpg");
  loadAllImages();

  function loadAllImages(){
      for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = onLoad; 
        img.onerror = onFail;
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
      }      
  }

  var imagesAllLoaded = function() {
    if (imagesOK+imagesFailed==imageURLs.length ) {

       // ALL IMAGES ARE NOW PROCESSED
       // ready to use loaded images
       // ready to handle failed image loads

       ctx1.drawImage(imgs[0],0,0,canvas1.width,canvas1.height);
       ctx2.drawImage(imgs[1],0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height);

    }
  };

  function onLoad() {
    imagesOK++;
    imagesAllLoaded();
  }

  function onFail() {
    // possibly log which images failed to load
    imagesFailed++;
    imagesAllLoaded();
  };   


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width=300 height=300></canvas><br/>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. That should be the issue. Nice example

Comment: Thank you very much! This is definitely a sure-fire way to make the pictures show.